# Error in MySQLSyntax - JSON

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb

I'm trying to do something very simple. I just want to create a table with one column which has the data type of JSON.

I get this error while trying to do it through the command prompt:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'JSON)' at line 1
```

Here is the create syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE test (jsonText JSON);
```

I believe that it is because JSON isn't a valid datatype. However when looking in the MySQL Workbench GUI, it includes the JSON data type. I just can't do anything with it.

Do I need to install a plugin?

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using? The `JSON` data type was introduced with version 5.7.8.

Comment: Im actually using MariaDB 10.1. But MariaDB incorporates all of MySQLs features

Comment: JSON datatype only available since MySQL 5.7.8: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Comment: Ahh. That's why. I just looked it up. I thought MariaDB was completely up-to-date with all MySQL releases. They are only up to MySQL 5.5. That sucks, I just found out how to use the blob data type though